# How does this JavaScript make it appear that an event fired from one class, is also fired from another class?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, riot.js

I'm working with a library called `RiotControl`, and `RiotControl` holds a collection of `Store` instances. It also wires up some event listeners on every store that's added to it:

https://github.com/jimsparkman/RiotControl/blob/master/demo/todo.tag#L31

```
var RiotControl = {
  _stores: [],
  addStore: function(store) {
    this._stores.push(store)
  }
}

['on','one','off','trigger'].forEach(function(api){
  RiotControl[api] = function() {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments)
    this._stores.forEach(function(el){
      el[api].apply(null, args)
    })
  }
})
```

A `Store` observes and fires events on itself:

https://github.com/jimsparkman/RiotControl/blob/master/demo/todostore.js#L21

```
function TodoStore() {
  ...
  self.on('todo_add', function(newTodo) {
    self.todos.push(newTodo) 
    self.trigger('todos_changed', self.todos)        
  })
}
```

In the above example, the store will fire a `todos_changed` event on itself. Somehow though, this event is also observable on the `RiotControl` object:

https://github.com/jimsparkman/RiotControl/blob/master/demo/todo.tag#L31

```
// Register a listener for store change events.
RiotControl.on('todos_changed', function(items) {
  self.items = items
  self.update()
})
```

It's unclear to me how this event is observable on `RiotControl` when it's fired from the `Store`. As far as I can tell, `RiotControl`, in the `forEach` loop, will dispatch events that are fired on it to each store it manages, and this is why `TodoStore` can observe `self.on('todo_add')`. I can't figure out how `self.trigger('todos_changed')` bubbles up to `RiotControl` though so that it's observable there as well. Anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The event is observable on RiotControl and triggerable via `self` because it was added to RiotControl via `RiotControl.addStore(todoStore)`, which adds it to `_stores` and then `applys` whatever was called on `self` or `RiotControl` later.

(see https://github.com/jimsparkman/RiotControl/blob/master/demo/index.html#L31 )